# AppEngine + django: is reliable to rely on both?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, in-app-purchase

I need to create a In-App-Purchase backend for a iPhone App, and think in build it on GAE.

However, after my experience in a recent gig in one of the largest GAE customers and reading stuff like this http://www.agmweb.ca/blog/andy/2286/, I wonder if right now is good idea (ie: reliable) to host a django+gae project like this. I expect low traffic in the first months. Mainly a API-based website with some web front-end.

Or exist any kind of hints so get possible get a reliable operation using django + gae? I'm using App engine Helper, but could switch to another implementation if is more rock solid.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience it seems that Django needs a bit of effort to get working correctly, and using it on AppEngine is a bit different to how you would use it otherwise. I suggest considering the possibility of using a different framework.

Personally, I suggest [Tipfy](http://www.tipfy.org/) as it was built specifically for App Engine, but there are quite a few frameworks I haven't even tried but have heard great things about.

IIRC the problem with Django poisoning instances due to exceeding the deadline has been solved.